# Get Socket's rooms before disconnect complete?

Tags: socket.io

Is it possible to get an array of rooms the client is connected to during/prior to the disconnect event?

Answer (score 0):

io.sockets.adapter.rooms gets all rooms and extraneous properties in which you can pick off the properties you desire